# Double quotes and \ inside jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to send a POST request to a web service (written in .NET) using jQuery Mobile . I am using jQuery Mobile along with PhoneGap for iOS and writing the code in XCode.

This is the code I am running -

```
var param = "{\"jsonText\":  \"{ \"username\" : \"Test\", \"password\" : \"testing123\" } \"} ";
                console.log(param)
                $.ajax({
                       url: "https://example.asmx/authenticateUser",
                       type: "POST",
                       dataType: "json",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       data:JSON.stringify(param),
                       success: function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                       },  
                       error: function(result){
                       console.log(result);
                       }  
                       });
```

This is giving me the following error -

```
    {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"Cannot convert object of type \\u0027System.String\\u0027 to type 

\\u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\\u0027\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   at 

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\\r\\n   at 

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData 

methodData)\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\"}","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Please help.

Comment: You can use single quotes to wrap strings in JavaScript.

Comment: why are you manually creating JSON string to begin with? Just create an object literal and let  `JSON` methods  manipulate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your json

```
"{\"jsonText\":  \"{ \"username\" : \"Test\", \"password\" : \"testing123\" } \"} "
```

would be this:

```
{
    "jsonText": "{
                    "username": "Test",
                    "password": "testing123"
                }"
}
```

And that was wrong, it should be:

```
{
    "jsonText":{
        "username": "Test",
        "password": "testing123"
    }
}
```

Equivalent json:

```
"{\"jsonText\":{\"username\":\"Test\", \"password\":\"testing123\"}}"
```

Or since your are passing a single object it must be:

```
{
    "username": "Test",
    "password": "testing123"
}
```

Equivalent json:

```
{\"username\":\"Test\",\"password\":\"testing123\"}
```

Remember that you don't have to put `""` quotes between `}` curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `JSON.parse` not `JSON.stringify`.   The former gets an object from a JSON string (what you have).  The latter turns a JavaScript structure into such a string.

Moreover your JSON is invalid.  There should be no quote around the `{`:

```
JSON.parse("{\"jsonText\":  { \"username\" : \"Test\", \"password\" : \"testing123\" } } ")
```